# Is it Possible to merge two documents in word using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am clueless how to make Table-object in the word document to WrapText style. 
I have two documents. First contains a table containing some data.
Second contains text.
Now, when I try to merge the two files, The First document I add is - the document containing table followed by the document containing only text.

Problem is -In the output file,  Table is on first page and text is on second page.
But, I want the text to be wrapped next to table. So, that I can show the table and text on the same page.

If there are some other ways of dealing with this, please do tell me.
Following is my code:-

```
    public static void MergeWithColumns(string[] filesToMerge, string outputFilename, bool insertPageBreaks, string documentTemplate)
    {
        object defaultTemplate = documentTemplate;
        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
        object pageBreak = Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak;
        object outputFile = outputFilename;

        // Create  a new Word application
        Word._Application wordApplication = new Word.Application();

        try
        { 
            // Create a new file based on our template
            Word._Document wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(
                                          ref defaultTemplate
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing);

            // Make a Word selection object.
            Word.Selection selection = wordApplication.Selection;

            // Loop thru each of the Word documents
            foreach (string file in filesToMerge)
            {
                // Insert the files to our template
                selection.InsertFile(
                                            file
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing);

                //Do we want page breaks added after each documents?
                if (insertPageBreaks)
                {
                    selection.InsertBreak(ref pageBreak);
                }
            }

            foreach (Word.Table tbl in wordDocument.Tables)
            {
                //tbl.AllowAutoFit = false;
                tbl.AllowAutoFit = true;
                tbl.AutoFitBehavior(Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent);
            }

            // Save the document to it's output file.
            wordDocument.SaveAs(
                            ref outputFile
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing);

            // Clean up!
            wordDocument = null;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //I didn't include a default error handler so i'm just throwing the error
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Finally, Close our Word application
            wordApplication.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please help me out with that..?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7582/Merging-Word-Documents-with-C

Comment: I gone through the article, But could not get proper guidance with my issue!

Comment: Can my Code be altered to meet the requirement... if possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this one..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.merge(v=office.14).aspx